# How to normalize data to a percent for further processing

Tags: c#

Using two threshold limits I have data that is being categorized into 3 (Low, Medium, and High) groups.  Each of these groups keeps a running count for one minute of both the total events and the total reading for all events during that time.  Every event is categorized into just one of the three groups and has at least 1 reading but could have as many as several hundred reading.  I need to normalize each of the 3 groups to a percentage between 0 and 1 while still maintaining all of the information with in the data.

What I’m currently doing is to convert each of the three events to % and each of the three readings to % then add each of the 2 values within a group and divide by 2.

I have included a jpg picture of some randomly selected data to help explain the problem and my current solution.

As the first 2 sets of numbers on the top row show this loses a lot of information because in both cases the Hi group has 100% of the activity but the first group has substantially more activity.

Any ideas, suggestion or input is welcome.  I am coding using Visual Studio 2013 and C#.  It would also be greatly appreciated that if any formulas or equations are presented that they come with enough explanation so that a non-mathematician can understand and convert them into code.

Also if this is not the correct forum for this question or there is a web site that applies I would be happy to pursue those options.

[image: Normalized Data]

Comment: How is the data structured/input formatted? What is the expected output?

Comment: Also, do you have code available already? It would be good to know what you already have to determine what you will be needing. Also, I see that the images provided are just the outcome of the total amount of readings / events divided by the actual amount of readings and events per category. Am I right there?

Comment: I don't think that your question is really clear, what is the output that you expect? In the answer you provide yourself you still do not provide the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure on how you will retrieve all the data available, but this example could show how to do it. It's not yet perfect (quick and dirty actually), but it is just an idea (it's based upon a console application):

For the example, I took the liberty to use dictionaries, but also lists could work (although some minor changes will need to be created...):

First fill a dictionary with event data (which I took from your second table):

```
//Fill a dictionary with some arbitrary event data
Dictionary<string, int> EventCategory = new Dictionary<string, int>();
EventCategory.Add("High", 99);
EventCategory.Add("Med", 220);
EventCategory.Add("Low", 78);
```

Next, you will also need the Reading values, which I also placed hardcoded in a dictionary here:

```
//Fill a dictionary with some arbitrary reading data
Dictionary<string, int> ReadingCategory = new Dictionary<string, int>();
ReadingCategory.Add("High", 537);
ReadingCategory.Add("Med", 445);
ReadingCategory.Add("Low", 145);
```

Now, the trick will be to combine all the data and calculate the normalized values (not percentages if you would ask me) that you use in your example. I used the following LINQ statements (which will have to be purified / improved):

```
 var result = from eventCat in EventCategory
              select new
              {
                //Places the "High", "Med"and "Low" category strings
                Key = eventCat.Key,     
                //Contains the value of the event for this category            
                EventValue = eventCat.Value,         
                //Constains the value of the amount of readings for this category
                ReadingValue = ReadingCategory.Where(x => x.Key.Equals(eventCat.Key)).Select(x => x.Value).First(),  
                //Calculates the normalized event (it's not a percentage)
                EventNormalized= eventCat.Value / (double)EventCategory.Sum(x => x.Value),
                //Calculates the normalized readings (it's not a percentage)
                ReadingNormalized = ReadingCategory.Where(x => x.Key.Equals(eventCat.Key)).Select(x => x.Value).First() / (double)ReadingCategory.Sum(x => x.Value),
                //Calculate the total of both normalized values (event and reading) and divided by 2
                TotalNormalized = (eventCat.Value / (double)EventCategory.Sum(x => x.Value) +
                ReadingCategory.Where(x => x.Key.Equals(eventCat.Key)).Select(x => x.Value).First() / (double)ReadingCategory.Sum(x => x.Value)) / 2
              };
```

Now this has generated a new (anonymous) type which holds the exact same table as your second table in the first image.

The only thing we now need to do, is to print in on screen. As I am using a Console Application, I do it by using Console.WriteLine. I trust you can alter it in any way you think it would fit.

```
//Now print it to the screen
Console.WriteLine("\tEvents\tReadings\tEvent%\tReading%\tTotal%{0}", Environment.NewLine);
foreach (var res in result)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t\t{3:0.####}\t{4:0.####}\t\t{5:0.####}", res.Key, res.EventValue, res.ReadingValue, res.EventNormalized, res.ReadingNormalized, res.TotalNormalized);
}

//Wait for the user to press enter (a bit ugly, but hey, this is quick and dirty)
Console.ReadLine();
```

The only thing you need to do, is copy all this code and place it within your

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   //Enter code here
}
```

code block.

My basic advice would be to think on how you would like the data to be represented. I cannot get into your head, so I made my own assumptions. As soon as you have that clear, you can focus on how to break down the algorithm. Which isn't really hard in this case :)

Feel free to try this. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks RvdV79 for your input.

It seems that I am being misunderstood.  Your code produces the exact same results as the percentages as in my original pictures.  This is not what I was asking but I think I may have solved it myself.

I was attempting to take each data point in isolation, when in fact I need to take into account the full range (min and max) of each of the 6 data values that make up the total observation.  I have done that and I’m getting better overall results.

My only issue now is that although I know for certain the min values I can never know for certain the max values.  At any time I could get a larger value in any of the 6 data value groups than I have ever seen in past data.  I intend to do two things to handle this.  First I will round up the max value for each group by the same % value in the hopes that it is not ever surpassed and second if it is passed I can recalculate the ranges taking into account the new max.

Thanks again.  It helps to write it out and read others questions and there take on it.

Comment: Indeed, I did not quite catch that particular question. My thoughts were how to get that table. My apologies for misunderstanding this. Usually it does help to put your ideas well structured and supported by code. Where you get into trouble, it would help to emphasize that particular part. If possible, provide some samples so that all StackOverFlow users can understand what you are trying to accomplish. It is hard to get inside someones head you know. That is also why CommuSoft asked his questions to get a better understanding.